# jest.createMockFromModule vs jest.mock

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm learning unit testing with `jest`. I can not understand the difference between the `jest.createMockFromModule` and `jest.mock`. Seems that they do the same? Can someone please explain me the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jest.mock` - does module auto-mocking and implicitly replaces imported module in the test file.
If you provide fabric function by the second argument it will define the module implementation like:

```js
jest.mock('./moduleName', () => ({
    default: 12345 // default constant definition
    MyClass: { // Named export object or class definition
        get: () => { /* get method class definition */ }
    }
    /* etc... */
}))
```

You also can [override only part](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials) of imported module.

`jest.createMockFromModule` - generates auto-mocked module and returns it as a value. It is useful in the [manual mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#examples). You can override required module values:

```js
// __mocks__/MyModule.js

const moduleName = jest.createMockFromModule('./moduleName');
moduleName.someNamedImport = () => 12345; // override method implementation

expect(moduleName.default.mocked).toBeTruthy(); // to check default import auto-mocking
expect(moduleName.someNamedImport()).toBe(12345)
```